# Upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 with live USB

Tags: upgrade, live-usb, 14.04

Is it possible to upgrade 13.10 to 14.04 with live USB?

Comment: No. To upgrade see http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1.Boot your computer from a usb flash drive.

2.Install without del your hard drive.

3.Done

Comment: You can also use Fakeroot to backup all your .deb . To a usb.